# Cloned HDD doest boot from 1TB to 2TB, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, xubuntu

my system wont boot after I installed the newly cloned HDD. Here's the full details.

I have a 1TB WD and 256Gb SSD. Corrupted windows is installed in SSD and Ubuntu 20.04 in HDD.

I tried to clone using CloneZilla but I always had an error which says

> The directory of this inputted image does not exist as attached.

So I trief to clone using DMDE.

After a few hrs, the whole 1TB is copied to my new 2TB Seagate.

Upon putting in the new HDD, the system will show the Ubuntu logo, then an error

> you need to load a kernel first

Pls advise help, and to where did I get the steps wrong? Ubuntu was just luckily installed for backup and Im new to this becauae my Windows just got corrupted. Thanks!

Edit1: Here's the pastebin link for the checks https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vS8gprjzsG/

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair%20& 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  I find new clean install & restore my data, settings & list of installed apps from my backups to be easier. Plus it then confirms my backups are complete.

Comment: @oldfred hi, thanks for the response. May I kindly confirm which pastebin link should I copy? Im really sorry as I am new user. thanks

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Comment above seemed to combine my two links. First one should not have escaped & but just a space and & to separate them. If you follow link, it will run boot-repair and give you the option to run the report. And then upload to a pastebin site, so we can see your details.

Comment: Hi @oldfred I got the pastebin report link. Should I just paste it here, or via DM? if there is any. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Post pastebin link in question above as an update.

Comment: @oldfred I have added it, pls let me know if it's working

Comment: You have mixed UEFI/gpt and BIOS/MBR. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives for 10 years. Ubuntu really should also then be installed in UEFI/gpt mode. Only because you have two drives you can have different boot modes, but have to go into UEFI and change default boot to BIOS/CSM/Legacy to boot Ubuntu and to UEFI to boot Windows. Better to backup sdb drive, convert to gpt & reinstall in UEFI mode. Note that conversion to gpt totally erases drive. This may convert saving data: http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html, & grub reinstall required.

Comment: @oldfred That is confirmed. Problem is my windows got corrupted, so instead of using UEFI, I changed to Legacy to use my backup OS, which was Ubuntu. Now, I have bought a new 2TB HDD to change my 1TB HDD. 1tb was cloned to 2tb. Upon using 1Tb, my ubuntu boots, but in 2tb, it doesnt and gets an error above. My plan is to have a back up, this 1 tb, reinstall my windows in ssd, but currently Im lost as I cant boot my new 2tb

Comment: The choice to boot live installer is normally either UEFI or BIOS. But the install boots based on settings in UEFI. Most newer UEFI will try to boot first choice and then may try another choice. But to boot Ubuntu you have to use BIOS mode in UEFI and choose sdb drive however UEFI refers to it. Because of these kinds of issue, I have preferred a new install & restore from backup. It proves backup has everything, plus you have old drive to update anything missing in your normal backup. I also prefer gpt even with BIOS boot as I originally used that 10 years ago with my BIOS only system.